# Cloth simulation 3D Blender gets weird

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, cloth-simulation, blenderkit

I'm new to blender and just learned cloth simulation. I'm having trouble with this kind of situation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: We would like to help, but at the moment your question is a little hard to understand. Can you please edit it and add what you have tried, what is the problem, and what you have done to try to fix it?